# UISearchBar inputAccessoryView issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uisearchbar

I've crate view controller and add a button as subview.

```
@implementation PredectiveViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 40)];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    UIButton *b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [b setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 0, 200, 40)];
    [b setTitle:@"Some button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [b addTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:b];
}

-(void)tapped:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Tapped");
}
```

Then set controllers view as input view

```
PredectiveViewController *pred = [[PredectiveViewController alloc] init];

[searchBar setInputAccessoryView:pred.view];
```

When i pressed the button first time, my program has crashed with error like

```
"[UIPopoverPresentationController tapped:] unrecognized selector
 sent to instance"
```

But now i have no error on crash.

About hierarchy:

I present view controller A in `UIPopoverController`, view controller A have `UITableViewController` as subview, which have `UISearchBar`, which have `inputAccessoryView` with `UIButton`.

Running on iOS 8.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You may have another View controller where you call tapped: on an Action? The code above looks good.

Comment: The problem is that you don't keep a reference to the `PredectiveViewController` instance.